# Python - re.sub return pattern rather than replacing

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am trying to revise a list of dictionary keys in Python 3 so that they are identifiable by the first set of numbers in the dictionary but it appears to be returning the regex pattern rather than the set of numbers.

```
>>>> import re
>>>>re.sub(r'GraphImages_[0-9]{2}_edge_media_to_caption_edges_0_node_text', '(?<=GraphImages_)\n{3}', 'GraphImages_99_edge_media_to_caption_edges_0_node_text')
'(?<=GraphImages_)\n{3}'
>>>>re.sub(r'GraphImages_[0-9]{2}_edge_media_to_caption_edges_0_node_text', '(?<=GraphImages_)\n{3}', 'GraphImages_123_edge_media_to_caption_edges_0_node_text')
'(?<=GraphImages_)\n{3}'
```

When the intended output from the above output would be `99` and `123` respectively.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. I am not very adept at the `re` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to extract the numbers, you need to find them, not to replace:

```
re.findall("GraphImages_([0-9]{2,})", yourstring)[0]
#'99'
```

In fact, in your case a split may be a better choice:

```
yourstring.split("_")[1]
#'99'
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a cumbersome workaround in the following

```
try_1 = re.sub('[^0-9]', "", 'GraphImages_99_edge_media_to_caption_edges_0_node_text')
try_2 = re.sub( '0$', "" , try_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^\D+(\d+).+
```

See a [**demo on regex101.com.**](https://regex101.com/r/5MFhgt/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I get the following curious traceback.
```error: bad escape \D at position 1``` which led to putting extra ```/``` to no avail

Comment: This is to say that I don't think it's a problem with your or my regex but my lack of understanding about ```re.sub```